# FSCalendar column line separator

Tags: ios, objective-c, fscalendar

I using fscalendar and I see that a new column separator in days cell.

These lines does't appear in iPhone 7 but in iPhone XS yes.

[image]

If somebody has a solution for this issue I appreciate you because I'm crazy with this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it!... in my code, I changed backgroundColor property of cell.titleLabel object. I comment this lines and column separator line is go out!

Regards!